# Regex to ignore youtube

Tags: regex

a little regex problem, easy as pie for the ones who know, impossible for the ones who doesn't :)

I have little experience with regex so i need your help on this. i have a pattern that matches URLs

```
[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]
```

this matches all URL's i just need to change this regex so it matches all URL's EXCEPT the "youtube.com" URL's.

```
http://www.google.com MATCH
http://example.com MATCH
http://asdasdasfsadfsdfasfsdfs.com MATCH
http://www.youtube.com MUST NOT MATCH
http://youtube.com MUST NOT MATCH
```

(i think you got the point)

Thank you in advance guys!

Comment: oh i almost forgot also `http://http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ` MUST NOT MATCH

Comment: If you don't want people to click on the link, enclose it with backticks `\`` (that will `format it as code`).

Comment: thanks Felix for the `tip` !!! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use negative lookahead as:

```
^(?!http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube\.com).*$
```

[**See it**](http://www.rubular.com/r/fIQOROJeEx)

Comment: It might work to combine this solution with the original regex to kick out any unwanted non-url formatted strings: `^(?!http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube\.com)[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]$`.

Comment: i tried this like `$active_links_text = ereg_replace("(?!http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube\.com)[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]","<a href=\"\\0\" target=\"_blank\">\\0</a>", $original_text);`    as you can see i am trying to make links inside a string "active" except the youtube ones. so a `http:\\www.google.com` will become `<a href="http:\\www.google.com">http:\\www.google.com</a>` but it doesnt work. i get a Warning: ereg_replace() [function.ereg-replace]: REG_BADRPT

Comment: forgot to mention this pattern could be anywhere inside the $original_text so i removed the ^ sign (i dont know if thats correct! heeeelp!)

Answer (score 2):

I propose a slight modification of codaddict's answer:

```
^(?!http:\/\/(?:.*\.)*youtube\.com).*$
```

This would also discard any other subdomains of youtube.com.

Comment: Though it would also match malformed URLs. D'oh.

Comment: It looks like it would filter out `http://sitereport.com/search?q=youtube.com` or anything else that started with `http://` and contained `.youtube.com`. Don't know if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex to

`[[:alpha:]]+://(?!(?:[^:/ ]+\.)?youtube.com)[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]`

Test here: http://rubular.com/r/Am4YFcCsf9

The key part is this `[^:/ ]`

The carrot says what there may not be between // and youtube.com. You may want to change it to not allow tabs `[^:/ \t]` or to make it to only allow certain characters  like . - letters numbers underscores `[\.\-A-Za-z0-9]` (also works `[\w\.\-]`)

**Edit: after reading your comment**

My suggestion is now

`[[:alpha:]]+://(?!(?:https?:/+)*(?:[^:/ ]+\.)?youtube.com)[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]`